# Clipping / cropping lines and fills in matplotlib on seaborn distplot kde-function

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Let's say I use seaborn to plot a distribution, it's median and standard deviation like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Get data
data = np.random.randn(6000)

# Compute statistics
median = np.median(data)
sigma = np.std(data)

low = median - sigma
hi = median + sigma

# Plot
sns.distplot(data)
plt.axvline(median, c='r')
plt.axvline(low, c='k')
plt.axvline(hi, c='k')
```

[image]

How would I go about "cropping" or "clipping" the lines, so they only appear below the kde-function of the distplot? The result should be something like this (quickly done with gimp):

[image]

Bonus question: How would I do the same with a `plt.fill_between()`, so that only the area under the curve is filled? I think I'm missing something easy here. I've already clipped fill_between calls to other elements before, but I don't know how to get coordinates of the function and how to do it with lines.

Is there an easy and concise way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to doing this is to find the data that corresponds to the smooth line that `kdeplot` adds to the graph and use its x and y coordinates.

The following code assumes that there is only one line in the plot --- with more than one line we have to find which line corresponds to the `kdeplot` line.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# Get data
data = np.random.randn(6000)

# Compute statistics
median = np.median(data)
sigma = np.std(data)

low = median - sigma
hi = median + sigma

ax = sns.distplot(data)
# get the line that sns uses for kdeplot; at this point in the code 
# there is only one line; if there are more we need to exract the correct
# one.
line = ax.lines[0].get_data()
# To get y for x=low, x=high and x=median we can interpolate the line data
ipf = interp1d(x=line[0], y=line[1])

ax.plot([low, low], [0, ipf(low)])
ax.plot([hi, hi], [0, ipf(hi)])
ax.plot([median, median], [0, ipf(median)]);
```

[image: Line to kdeplot]

We can use the line data as input to `fill_between`.

```py
plt.fill_between(line[0], np.zeros(len(line[0])), line[1]);
```

[image: Line to kdeplot and fill_between]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by accessing the smooth distribution line plotted by the `distplot`. As to the bonus part, I would recommend asking a new question and not mix two problems in the same question.

The trick here is to get the x-value closest to `low`, `median` and `high` and then use `plt.ylines` instead of `plt.axvline` to plot a vertical line from y=0 to the desired y-value.

```
# Plot
ax = sns.distplot(data)
x, y = ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()
plt.vlines(median, 0, y[np.argmin(abs(x-median))], color='r')
plt.vlines(low, 0, y[np.argmin(abs(x-low))], color='k')
plt.vlines(hi, 0, y[np.argmin(abs(x-hi))], color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]